# How to obtain a minimal key from functional dependencies?

Tags: sql, database, normalization, relation

I need some help and guidelines.

I have the following relation: `R = {A, B, C, D, E, F}` and the set of functional dependencies

```
F = {
  {AB -> C};
  {A  -> D};
  {D  -> AE};
  {E  -> F};
}
```

What is the primary key for R ?

If i apply inference rules i get these additional Function dependencies:

```
D -> A
D -> E
D -> F

D -> AEF

A -> E
A -> F
A -> DEF
```

How do I continue?

Comment: I think that A and D are 1-1 equivalent in the scheme.

Comment: This process doesn't necessarily determine a primary key (a single key). ("Primary key" is well on its way to being mainly a SQL concept, and not a relational concept.) This process, correctly applied, will give you a *set* of candidate keys.  How to choose a primary key from a set of candidate keys is not part of the process.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This process will give you candidate keys :))

Answer (score 6):

There is a well known algorithm to do this. I don't remember it, but the excercise seems to be simple enough not to use it.

I think this is all about transitivity:

```
CurrentKey = {A, B, C, D, E, F}
```

You know D determines E and E determines F. Hence, D determines F by transitivity. As F doesn't determine anything, we can remove it and as E can be obtained from D we can remove it as well:

```
CurrentKey = {A, B, C, D}
```

As AB determines C and C doesn't determine anything we know it can't be part of the key, so we remove it:

```
CurrentKey = {A, B, D}
```

Finally we know A determines D so we can remove the latter from the key:

```
CurrentKey = {A, B}
```

If once you have this possible key, you can recreate all functional dependencies it is a possible key.

PS: If you happen to have the algorithm handy, please post it as I'd be glad to re-learn that :)

Comment: Thank you so much :) I haven't heard of any algorithm i just know some inference rules that can be used to derive new functional dependencies :))

Comment: @user1285737 No need to thanks, that's what accepting answers is there for :) Anyway, there IS an algorithm that will get you the right result regardless of the complexity of the relations and functional dependencies. I wish I could remember it :'(

Comment: Isn't {B, D} also a Candidate key and therefore can be picked as Primary key ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is. It is possible to have more than one candidate key, but only one will be the primary key.

Comment: Thank you :) I assume that I need to know all the candidate keys when I transform the relation into 2NF, 3NF etc etc ??

Comment: Well, it should be enough with the minimal one. In this cas it is the same as both have a length of 2

Comment: Thanks :) Just one last question :) When I want to transform the relation into 2NF i encounter some problems. 

The relation is not in 2NF because E is determined by a, ie E is determined by a part of the candidate/prime key. I create two new relations: R1= {A, B, C, D, F} and R1 = {A, E}. The "problem" is that E is determinated by A, but they are not in the same relation. Is it still right ? Should there just exist a foreign key beetween them ?

Comment: There are two keys of R: AB and DB. It is never good enough to find just any one key and stop there. The concept of having just one "primary" key is arbitrary and irrelevant in such exercises.

Comment: @user1285737,  R1= {A, B, C, D, F} and R2 = {A, E} satisfies 2NF. R2 = {D, E} would do just as well. Yes you would normally expect to create a constraint to keep R1,R2 consistent.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks you :) Isn't R1 and R2 also in 3NF ?

Comment: Is R1 = {A, B, C, F}, R2= {A, E } and R3 = {A, D } in BCNF ? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Algorithm: Key computation (call with x = ∅)

```
procedure key(x;A;F)
foreach  ! B 2 F do
if   x and B 2 x and B ̸2  then
return; /* x not minimal */
fi
od
if x+ = A then
print x; /* found a minimal key x */
else
X   any element of A  x+;
key(x [ fXg;A;F);
foreach  ! X 2 F do
key(x [ ;A;F);
od
fi
```